# Select values that exists in array, but do not exits in database?

Tags: postgresql

I have got DB with `ID`s: `1 2 3 4 5`. I need to return elements that exists in my array (simple list of data that usually specifying in `IN ( ... )` ), but DO NOT exits in DB.
For example checking values: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`.

So query should return `6, 7`. How can I do it's with PostgreSQL?

Comment: I don't understand the output.  Also, when say "array" are you using Postgres arrays or do you just generally mean a collection of numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be solved using `except`

```
select *
from unnest(array[1,2,3,4,5,6]) as t(id)
except
select id
from the_table
```

With some test data:

```
select *
from unnest(array[1,2,3,4,5,6]) as t(id)
except
select id
from (values (1), (2), (3), (4) ) as the_table(id)
```

returns

```
id
--
 5
 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t (id) as (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5))
select u.id
from
    t
    right join
    unnest(array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) u (id) on t.id = u.id
where t.id is null
;
 id 
----
  6
  7
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a query that excludes all elements in a list you can use the `NOT IN` statement.

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

In your case you can create the query from your array.

Comment: This will not show values that do not exist in the table